# Convert from NSMutable to String

Tags: xcode

I have a data in NSMutableData type. Can I convert the data to a string format.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```